# My data is partitioned and I want to use a loop to retrieve the data in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, database-partitioning

My DB is partitioned by a date field and I've been told that setting a where clause to retrieve data between date X and date Y is a lot slower than manually going through each date field, pulling the data and then inserting it into a newly created table.

My question is that is possible to make this automated using a loop. I've looked at various forums but they seem pretty intricate for something I think would be fairly simple in a regular programming language.

e.g.

```
dates = (1/1/16,1/1/17,1/1/18)
counter=1
do while counter< y
Insert into Table
Select * from TableX
where date(counter) = 'X'
counter=counter+1
loop
```

instead of

```
create table Table as
select * from TableX
where date in (1/1/16,1/1/17,1/1/18)
```

Thanks,
Stephan

Comment: Who told you that it was a lot slower, and what evidence did they provide? A single statement is usually faster breaking it up into multiple smaller chunks. You'd have to use PL/SQL to do multiple inserts in a loop; certainly possible but rarely necessary for this sort of scenario...

Comment: A DBA had informed me as to why my queries were running so slowly and I just tested it myself. When I tried to pull information over multiple date periods it took considerably longer than piecing together one date at a time.

Comment: First measure the time of one "big" query with `BETWEEN DATE-Start AND DATE-End` with X days between these two dates, and then measure a total time of X queries, each for a single day. Most likely, the latter will be slower, and if not, then add EXPLAIN PLANs for both queries to the question for analysis of the reason.

Comment: OK thanks I will give that a go